# Set default YML values

Tags: yaml

I have a yaml file with a number of entries of the form

```
item1:
  name: item1
  stem: item1

items2:
  name: item2
  stem: item2
```

Is there a way to DRY this up since the information for each record follows the same form?

I'd like to specify somehow that whatever I make the name of the entry, it should also be used for the name and stem.

I know that I can tag entries with `&tag` and reference them in other entries with `<<: *tag` but that's for the actual content and not the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML, as far as I know doesn't have facilities for looping, and generating dynamic content as of the 1.2 spec: http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html. It is simply a standard for serializing data. However if your goals is to generate similar objects with no repetition in the YAML file, you can use an implementation of YAML, and return an Array in a programming language, such as Ruby.

The Ruby implementation of YAML offers "generic support for serializing objects from any class available in Ruby.": http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#objects This means you can create an Array object in Ruby containing the entries you have repeated in the YAML file by creating a custom class.

This example class below will generate `x` items in an array, as defined by the YAML key `items`.

Structure the YAML file like so:

```
--- !ruby/object:Foo
  items: 2
```

*Note*: The class name to call is specified on the first name, using the Object syntax defined at: http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#objects

And in Ruby, define your class, and load your YAML file for parsing:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :items

  def initialize(items)
    @items = items
  end

  def generate
    x = 1
    result = []
    while x < @items do
      result.push({ "item#{x}" => {"name" => "item#{x}", "stem" => "item#{x}"} })
      x+=1
    end
    result
  end
end

foo = YAML.load_file('/path/to/yaml.yml') # => #<Foo:0xa1ff694 @items=2>

foo.generate # => [{"item1"=>{"name"=>"item1", "stem"=>"item1"}}, {"item2"=>{"name"=>"item2", "stem"=>"item2"}}]
```

The YAML file is loaded after our class `Foo` is defined. `Foo` takes an integer at initialization, which is the number of items we will create when `generate` is called. `generate` then loops this many times, and pushes a new object to an array, which is then returned.

You will have to explicitly call `generate` in this example, since you cannot return anything other than self from `initialize`.

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are seeking, but it is a possibly way to keep the YAML structure DRY, by outsourcing the looping and creation of objects in a custom class.

This approach can also be used in other languages, depending on whether their YAML implementation supports custom serialization classes. See http://yaml.org/ for additional language implementation libraries.